# Android notifications in a xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-pendingintent

I'm working in a xamarin forms app, and I'm trying to develop an Android notification with two buttons:

- In the first one you can write text, and this text must be retrieve to one of the ViewModels.
- The second one should open a view of the app.

I have no experience with intents nor Android, and so far I can show the notification with the two buttons:
[notification example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnRbY.jpg)

The class in charge of showing the notification is `LocalNotifications : ILocalNotifications` class in the Android solution:

```
class LocalNotifications : ILocalNotifications
{
    const string channelId = "default";
    const string channelName = "Default";
    const string channelDescription = "The default channel for notifications.";

    ...

    bool channelInitialized = false;
    int messageId = 0;
    int replyPendingIntentId = 0;
    int photoPendingIntentId = 0;

    NotificationManager manager;

    public event EventHandler NotificationReceived;

    public static LocalNotifications Instance { get; private set; }

    public LocalNotifications() => Initialize();

    public void Initialize()
    {
        if (Instance == null)
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel();
            Instance = this;
        }
    }

    public void SendNotification(string title, string message)
    {
        if (!channelInitialized)
        {
            CreateNotificationChannel();
        }
        Show(title, message);
    }

    public void ReceiveNotification(string title, string message)
    {
        var args = new NotificationEventArgs()
        {
            Title = title,
            Message = message,
        };
        NotificationReceived?.Invoke(null, args);
    }

    private static readonly string KEY_TEXT_REPLY = "key_text_reply";

    AndroidX.Core.App.RemoteInput remoteEntryInput = new AndroidX.Core.App.RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
            .SetLabel("Escribir entrada")
            .Build();

    private Intent replyIntent;
    private Intent photoIntent;

    public void Show(string title, string message)
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AndroidApp.Context, channelId)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(message)
            .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(AndroidApp.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha))
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);


        NotificationCompat.Action reply = CreateReplyIntent(title, message);

        builder.AddAction(reply);

        

        NotificationCompat.Action image = CreateImageIntent();

        builder.AddAction(image);

        Notification notification = builder.Build();
        manager.Notify(messageId++, notification);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Action CreateReplyIntent(string title, string message)
    {
        //replyIntent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        replyIntent = new Intent();
        replyIntent.PutExtra(TitleKey, title);
        replyIntent.PutExtra(MessageKey, message);

        // Build a PendingIntent for the reply action to trigger.
        PendingIntent replyPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(AndroidApp.Context, replyPendingIntentId++, replyIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        // Create the reply action and add the remote input.
        return new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha,
                        "Escribir entrada", replyPendingIntent)
                        .AddRemoteInput(remoteEntryInput)
                        .Build();
    }

    NotificationCompat.Action CreateImageIntent()
    {
        //photoIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        photoIntent = new Intent(AndroidApp.Context, typeof(MainActivity));
        //photoIntent.SetFlags( ActivityFlags.LaunchAdjacent | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        // Build a PendingIntent for the reply action to trigger.
        PendingIntent phtoPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(AndroidApp.Context, photoPendingIntentId++, photoIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        return new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(Resource.Drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha,
                        "Sacar foto", phtoPendingIntent)
                        .Build();
    }

    void CreateNotificationChannel()
    {
        manager = (NotificationManager)AndroidApp.Context.GetSystemService(AndroidApp.NotificationService);

        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var channelNameJava = new Java.Lang.String(channelName);
            var channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelNameJava, NotificationImportance.Default)
            {
                Description = channelDescription
            };
            manager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        channelInitialized = true;
    }

}
```

Which a don't get is how/where the app can react to those PendintIntents and how to pass the information from the android solution to the xamarin forms model.

Comment: There are two parts to the solution. The first part you might have done in your shown code (I didn't look at it yet); please check [Local Notifications on Android doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications) to make sure you have that part done. The second part (which is what you are asking), is how to get that info from the platform (Android) code, to the xamarin forms code. Please read [Xamarin Forms DependencyService](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction).

Comment: ... I realize that DependencyService seems a bit complicated the first time you write one. But its worth mastering this approach. Because then you have a clean technique to add any functionality from any platform. If you get stuck, then add to your question the DependencyService code you wrote, and exactly where you are stuck, and what the problem is.

Comment: Thank you so much, both links really helped me!

Comment: Glad those links helped. If you have it working now, it would be great if you add an *answer* below (you can answer your own question) showing the working code. This will let others know how this works. Thanks. [Then after 48 hours pass, you can "accept" your own answer, to make it clear that it is solved.]